# how to configure aws ec2 instance in api gateway for reverse proxy

Tags: amazon-ec2, swagger, aws-api-gateway, reverse-proxy

I deployed Swagger APIs in an ec2 instance working with port number. Then, I want to integrate with API gateway for reverse proxy and cors policy. How can I do that? Can any one help on this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is **off-topic** as you did not provide any partial or rough attempt. This forces us to infer what you exactly intended, and answers to such questions are usually too broad anot not reliable in the long run here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i am able to combine all swagger apis in api gateway.Import the swagger json file in apigateway and add the integration methods according to the requirement either lambda or html or aws services and deploy the api.